# Transform content in table to JSON formatted using PowerQuery

Tags: json, api, powerquery

I am new to PowerQuery. Basically I import a csv using PowerQuery and need to pass all content within CSV as JSON formatted. I use PowerQuery to consume a web service API.

How can I do this please?

for example my csv has very simply column1-3 and they are text formatted.

Thank you
Peddie

Comment: I'm confused. Does your CSV file actually contain JSON format?  Are you trying to import a file or a web service?

Comment: My file is CSV that I imported to Power Query it doesnt cotnain JSON format at all but I want to convert the content of my CSV to JSON formatted - is this doable? Thank you

Comment: Power Query only outputs to Excel Tables or the Excel Data Model. So you cannot do this directly.

Once you have the data in Excel Table form, you might find a viable Excel-to-JSON solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert CSV to JSON, just apply ***find/replace*** to plain text - replace delimiter ";" with comma "," (or quotes and commas for text values). Then replace new lines with square brackets "],[". After all embrace all with double square braces

**Assume your CSV-text is**

```
1;2;3
1;2
1
1;2
```

**First you replace ";" with ","**

```
1,2,3
1,2
1
1,2
```

**Then replace new lines with "],["**

```
1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[1,2
```

**Embrace**

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[1,2]]
```

## Here is an example

```
let

src =
"1;2;3
1;2
1
1;2",
    replace_semicolon=Text.Replace(src, ";", ","),
    replace_newlines =Text.Replace(replace_semicolon, "#(lf)", "],["),
    braces="[["&replace_newlines&"]]",
    json=Json.Document(braces)
in
    json
```